# How to convert csv data from storage account to Excel File in Azure Synapse

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Every time when we run the notebook it has generated a new Excel file, here I loaded data from storage account to notebook by using data frame and was unable to generate an excel file from there and I have tried many ways but couldn't out the right data frame to do the job.

```
%%pyspark
import pandas as pd
df=spark.read.load('abfss://gen2container@gen2strgacc.dfs.core.windows.net/xyz/xxxx.csv', format='csv'
, header=True
)
display(d f)

df1 = spark.read.load('abfss://gen2container@gen2strgacc.dfs.core.windows.net/xyz/xxx.csv', format='csv'
, header=True
)
display(df1)
```

From the above data frame I'm able to load data.

```
with pd. Excel Writer('Validated_data.xlsx') as writer:
    df.to_ excel(writer, sheet name='Required data')
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet name='Split data')`
```

from the above code I tried to generate an Excel file, but I'm an getting error.